# A word or phrase for phone service working only one-way

Tags: vocabulary, telephone

I have a monthly phone subscription, and I need to recharge it. Since I have not yet paid for it, the service is only working one-way. Meaning that I can only receive calls, but I cannot make any calls. Is there a word or phrase to for this situation?

Comment: It is not a vocabulary regarding phone subscriptions as phone companies will not list that option.

Comment: @Rathony I think OP meant "regarding my subscription status". The subscription is not fully working due to lack of payment.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "to for my line condition" in the last sentence, but if you want to talk about your "line" (and not your "service" [as in AP's good answer]), you could say "your line's usage options/capabilities have been halved/cut in half."

Comment: "inbound only" vs "outbound only", or "incoming only" vs "outgoing only".

Comment: thanks for your comments, I tried to clarify the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This phrase should work for you:

> You have failed to pay your bill, so your service is **restricted to incoming calls only**.

EDIT: As suggested by @Hot Licks, you can also use "inbound" instead of "incoming".

Answer (score 2):

You could use the verb "[***suspend***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suspend)" to mean:

> to stop (something) for a usually short period of time.

[Merriam-Webster]

You could say:

> "The phone company (has) 
>   suspended (my) outgoing calls"

Answer (score 2):

The technical term is "half duplex."

A full duplex channel has two way communications. A half duplex only enables one party to communicate at a time.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_(telecommunications)

A "simplex" is a strictly one way channel.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_communication

Comment: Sorry, wrong kind of one way.

Comment: Simplex is one-way *while someone is transmitting*, but both parties can send data to the other (just not at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

You could say your service is currently **unidirectional**.

> moving or operating in a single direction.
>   (*[Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=unidirectional)*)

This relies on your reader inferring that inbound and outbound are directions, but I think most people will follow your meaning easily. I have actually used this word myself when describing the same problem to my phone company.

Comment: I don't know if anyone would ever say this

Comment: that's a good word but I think it better fits with more academic articles.